# Error with installation of pycocotools for Detr Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, pycocotools

I'm trying to use Detr Tensorflow models and need to install pycocotools. On a Windows 10 PC, I'm executing this in a Visual Studio Code.  I'm following the steps provided in this
GitHub repo : https://github.com/Visual-Behavior/detr-tensorflow#install

I attempted to pip-install pycocotools and received the following error (fails to construct wheel):
[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brpcj.png)

Any idea on how to remove this error ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the error output.

You need to install Microsoft C++ Build Tools.